# Karma + Jasmine CSS element null from DOM

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner

I use Karma and Jasmine to test mmy javascript code (no Angular in the case of the issue). When I launch the units tests, I have this issue for the first js file :
**Chrome 38.0.2125 (Windows 8.1) ERROR
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'style' of null**

The code where this error happen is :

```
var source = document.getElementById('workzone');
hw = hw - hauteurmodif;
source.style.height = hw + 'px';
```

I have this message for each similar case : when I try to use a element from a CSS file (here workzone). 
However there's no error with a normal execution, the css and the element exist, the js script files are called at the end of  (after the css links), and in karma.conf.js, the call order is correct :

```
//css
'app/css/*.css',
// libraries
...
// our app
'app/js/*.js',
// test
'test/unit/**/*.js'
```

I thinks the CSS are not loaded in the DOM when the tests run. I try to use differents browser, there was no differences.

Moreover, I tested to use Jasmine-Jquery, it was without effect.

Thanks for your help

Comment: you can't "use an element from a CSS file" so the fact that you load CSS files before JS files has no effect. You use an element from the DOM, so an element with an id of `workzone` needs to exist in the DOM. Are you loading your HTML templates or manually appending `workzone` element to the DOM somewhere?

Comment: It works when I launch index.html and document.getElementById('workzone') isn't null. However it is when I launch the test with karma. I'm using ths configuration file, so I don't unserstand why there is a problem with the DOM : https://github.com/arey/angular-musicbrainz/blob/master/config/karma.conf.js

Comment: How can I add these elements to the DOM ?

Comment: Based on that config file, you should load the partials (HTML templates) before executing your tests.

Comment: I moved 'app/partials/directives/**/*.html' just before 'test/unit/**/*.js'. The problem persist